# Regular lattice polygons

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, geometry-of-numbers

Suppose I want to construct an $N$-gon in the plane whose vertices are integer lattice points, and which is close to a regular $N$-gon (which means, the ratio of longest to the shortest side is within $\epsilon_1$ of $1,$ and the ratio of the largest to the smallest angle is within $\epsilon_2$ of $1$) The question is: is there any sort of reasonable upper/lower bound to the size (area or diameter) of such a thing? This is clearly related to diophantine approximation in the following way: take the "standard" regular $N$-gon (one whose vertices are $N$-th roots of unity,) and blow it up by a factor of $t$ until wall the vertices ($t$ times the roots of unity) are close to lattice points. How big does $t$ need to be in terms of some "closeness" bound?

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you are asking for, but here is something very elementary : let $\ell(i,t)$ be the Gauss integer closest to $t\omega^i$ (with $\omega=e^{2i\pi/n}$). Then by the triangle inequality, you have that the length $d(i,i+1,t)$ between $\ell(i,t)$ and $\ell(i+1,t)$ satisfies the inequality
$2t\pi/n-\sqrt{2}\leq d(i,i+1,t)\leq 2t\pi/n+\sqrt{2}$...

Thus you can always find an $\sqrt{2}/m$ good approximation with integers of norm smaller than $m$ ...

Comment: @few_reps that is a nice observation! It does not deal with angles (though that is not too hard to correct by elementary geometry), but also, on general principles, I would expect the error term to be of order $1/m^2,$ not $1/m.$

Comment: This would be kind of a miracle : even if you can approximate $\omega^i$ by elements $h_n^{(i)}/k_n^{(i)}$ for each $i$ with $N(\omega^i- h_n^{(i)}/k_n^{(i)}) <1/N(k_n^{(i)})^2$, (this is possible since $\mathbf Z[i]$ is euclidean) I can see no reason why the $k_n^{(i)}$'s could not be prime to each other ...

Comment: Lest anyone think it possible to get an $N$-gon with vertices all at integer lattice points in the plane: This is only possible when $N = 4$. **Citation:** Klobučar, D. (1998). On nonexistence of an integer regular polygon. Mathematical Communications, 3(1), 143-146. (From http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568709/regular-n-gon-in-the-plane-with-vertices-on-integers/568721#568721)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) gives best possible answer for large $N$. We can only reduce the number of simultaneous approximations using symmetries of $N$-gon. For example for $8$-gon it is necessary to approximate only one number $1/\sqrt2$ among $8$ numbers $e^{2\pi ik/8}$ $(k=0,\ldots 7)$.

But starting from arbitrary $N$-gon inscribed into the unit circle we can find $t\le R$ such that 
$$|tx_1-a_1|\le\frac1{R^{\frac1{2N}}},|ty_1-b_1|\le\frac1{R^{\frac1{2N}}},\ldots |tx_N-a_N|\le\frac1{R^{\frac1{2N}}},|ty_N-b_N|\le\frac1{R^{\frac1{2N}}},$$
where $(x_1,y_1), \ldots, (x_N,y_N)$ are coordinates of initial $N$-gon. It means that we can achieve $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2\asymp t^{-1-\frac1{2N}}$ in the circle of radius $t$ for infinitely many $t$.

If we want a better exponent, we can do the following. For arbitrary $N$ we can take $x_1=1$, $y_1=0$ (no approximation needed). The rest part of vertices is symmetrical. So for odd $N$ we need to approximate $(N-1)/2$ points ($N-1$ coordinates), for $N\equiv2\pmod4$ $(N-2)/4$ points ($(N-2)/2$ coordinates), for $N\equiv4\pmod8$ $(N-4)/8$ points, for $N\equiv0\pmod8$ $(N-2)/4$ points $1+(N-8)/8$ coordinates.

Also there is an algorithm (based on discrete Fourier transform) of complexity $O(t^2)$ which allows to find all best possible solutions in the circle of radius $t$. This algorithm was published in [Algebra and number theory for mathematical schools. Collected problems](http://iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/emath23.pdf) (Russian, see page 138).

It is very simple. We need so specify only one vertex to define our regular $N$-gon. So we take all points $A_1=(x_1,y_1)$ such that $0\le y_1\le x_1\le t$. For each $A_1$ we define $A_2',\ldots,A_N'$ rotating $A_1$ around the origin, and $A_2,\ldots,A_N$ as nearest integer points to $A_2',\ldots,A_N'$. After that it necessary to check the quality of resulting $N$-gon. We can say that $A_1,\ldots,A_N$ are $N$ complex numbers and calculate discrete Fourier series. First Fourier coefficient gives main cycle ($|C_1|\approx |OA_1|$) and the rest part of Fourier series forms an error term.

Comment: So are you saying that for a regular $N$-gon one can get a better exponent?

Comment: And is there a reference for the algorithm? That sounds very interesting...

Comment: I've added the refference and algorithm description. Also exponents were corrected.

Comment: @Alexey : I did not know of the simultaneous approximation. I guess that if rather than doing it in $\mathbf R$ relatively to $\mathbf Z$ you do it in $\mathbf C$ relatively to $\mathbf Z[i]$, you can even obtain $\varepsilon_1\sim \varepsilon_2\sim t^{−1−1/N}$ ...

Comment: I agree that $\mathbb(Z}[i]$ is better. It allows to average over rotation. But in $\mathbb(R}$ we also can save at least half coordinates using symmetrical positions of initial $N$-gon. For best possible estimates we have to check everything more carefully.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Actually, there is something funny. If you look at this paper: http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/cvxl.pdf you will see that the minimial area of convex lattice polygon with $n$ vertices is cubic in $n.$ But the one you construct (unless I am missing something, which is likely) is _quadratic_ in $n.$ Thoughts?

Comment: In our case number of vertices is fixed. For small $R$ vertices can coinside. Polygon will be convex only for large $R$. (We can run this algorithm even for $100$-gon inside a circle of radius $2$.